# How do I embed toll-free numbers in Messenger Bots?

Tags: bots, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, messenger

How do I embed tollfree numbers in Messenger Bot Call buttons?

As per documentation, numbers need to have country codes, however, that's not how tollfree number works.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/buttons/call/

For e.g. an NZ tollfree number 0800123456 works, but +640800123456 doesn't.
Embedding 0800123456 produces an erroneous number in the phone App, most likely due to incorrect formatting.

Comment: come on who downvotes this

Comment: correction, embedding '0800123123' dials correctly on iOS but not Android